# Is there a way to share a texture between two contexts / threads using OpenGL on Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, textures

I want to have two threads. One thread writes into a texture using an FBO and the other uses it to render to the screen.
This can be done on windows etc, but how do I do it on Android?
I am using GL ES 2, and am using Textureview
I have read about the egl image extensions but I cannot figure out to use them
http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/extensions/KHR/EGL_KHR_image.txt
http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/extensions/KHR/EGL_KHR_image_base.txt
I read that the egl extensions are not fully supported on all platforms. Is it ok to use it on Android?
I cannot use something that is not assured to work properly.

This is what I read at this link:
http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/7319-EGLImage-on-Android-NDK

1. The EGL image extensions are not as necessary on Android now that the new TextureView class has been added with Android 4.0. Use TextureView to transfer texture images between OpenGL ES and the Canvas API.

I am using a TextureView. How do I use it to 'transfer texture images' ?

Also I read somewhere that egl defines textures as shared by default. What does this mean? How do I use the texture in a different context if it is already defined as shared?

I do not want to make the same context current in the other thread as I want the texture loading to be done without blocking the render to screen. Does this make sense?
I do not have much experience with OpenGL.

Apparently, firefox uses the same thing that I am trying to use
 http://snorp.net/2011/12/16/android-direct-texture.html
But I can't understand how I should do it.

I am using Java, not NDK.

Answer (score 1):

You have described the way OpenGL ES works on Android by default.  In other words, you use the SurfaceTexture provided by TextureView to render OpenGL ES by one thread.  Android's Surfaceflinger will then composite that SurfaceTexture to the display as part of it's normal View compositing - by another thread.

The EGL Image extensions are for getting pointers to the surfaces, which requires native code and is unnecessary.  Use TextureView instead.  There is an example app that uses TextureView in the Android SDK (although it uses the SurfaceTexture for camera video rather than OpenGL ES rendering):

```
sources\android-17\com\android\test\hwui\GLTextureViewActivity.java
```

So, use the SurfaceTexture (which is provided to the onSurfaceTextureAvailable() callback when the TextureView is created) to create the EGL Surface with eglCreateWindowSurface().  That SurfaceTexture will be the target of your OpenGL ES rendering and it will be displayed in the associated TextureView.

```
EGLSurface EglSurface = mEgl.eglCreateWindowSurface(mEglDisplay, maEGLconfigs[0], surfaceTexture, null);
mEgl.eglMakeCurrent(mEglDisplay, EglSurface, EglSurface, mEglContext);
```

I think this article will help:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what I want to do.
If I use the SurfaceTexture, will I be able to control what part of the texture is drawn?

This is what I want to do:
The texture will be large. A part of it should be displayed on the TextureView. On a Touch event, the part of the texture that is displayed changes.

Comment: I recommend you change what is rendered on the one SurfaceTexture. But, you can bind the first SurfaceTexture to address it as a texture with texture coordinates to render it onto another SurfaceTexture (render to texture), which would be the one displayed by the TextureView.